# error: error setting owner of a.s to uid 0 and gid 0: Operation not permitted

Tags: logrotate

While running the command `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/applogrotate`. I get the error `error: error setting owner of a.s to uid 0 and gid 0: Operation not permitted`. Inside the applogratate file, I have written `create 0664 root root` which I think is the cause of the error. Can someone help with a resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `logrotate` as root if you want to be able to create log files as root:

```
sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/applogrotate
```

(assuming `sudo` is configured appropriately).

Comment: sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/applogrotate?

Comment: If you want, but you shouldn’t need to specify `/usr/sbin` because that’s on root’s path by default.

Comment: Sure Thanks a lot. Will accept the answer

Comment: Getting another error - error: skipping a.s because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.

Comment: Please help with this

Comment: I hope you figured it out, but basically you need to add a line `su <username> <groupname>` to your logrotate config to each log file config section